# Remove Intel Push Pins

Tags: computer-building, heatsink

Intel's pushpins are awful. I'm trying to install a screw mount, but I need to remove the push pins that are on my heatsink. How do I remove them? Am I supposed to cut them? If so, how?

Comment: Be careful whatever you end up trying to do...

Answer (score 2):

Ok well I ended up breaking the push pins, but standard tweezers can be used to pull the black tabs that are holding the black part of the push pin to the white part. Then its a matter of twisting the black piece off (usually breaking it), and then easily slipping out the white part.

Answer (score 1):

Are these the same pins used on the LGA775 heatsinks?  If so, you just need to take a screwdriver and turn the pin counter clock wise about a quarter turn.  Then you can just pull to pop it out.

**EDIT**

OK, I get what you are trying to do now.  Solution: buy a new heat sink.

Comment: Certainly that's what I did to remove them from the motherboard. I'm talking about removing them from the heatsink itself.

Comment: +1 because Pyrolistical shouldn't be downvoted for answering a vague question.